# Is the phrase " in the direction" commonly used?

Tags: prepositions

I came across the sentence "The bird went off in the direction from which it had come.". I wonder if why "in" was used instead of "to".

Is "in" commonly used instead of "to" like I go in the U.S instead of I go to the U.S.

Comment: *In* is virtually obligatory with *direction*: "Go in X direction" or "Go in the direction of X". *To* or *toward* is usual with a goal, but *direction* names a path, not a goal, even if it is defined as a path to a specific goal as "in the direction of [goal]".

Answer (score 1):

"to" defines a destination, and "in the direction" defines a route to that destination.

If the US is a place you want to go, you say

> I would like go **to** to the US

If you were to sail away from the east coast of Japan, you would say

> I am heading **in the direction** of the US

or

> I am heading **toward** the US.

The more natural way of expressing the original sentence would be

> The bird went back to where it came from

but some people don't like sentences with prepositions (eg from) at the end: to avoid this, they use complicated sentences to say simple things.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is "I am heading to the direction of the US" wrong?

Comment: Yes, @YuuichiTam, it's wrong.